# Modeling Table-Per-Type in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, inheritance

I have read the following post [How do you effectively model inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190296/how-do-you-effectively-model-inheritance-in-a-database) about inheritance in databases. Unfortunately I could not find anything in the PostgreSQL books from Packt.  And now I'm a bit confused if my approach is an overkill and doesn't even belong in the database or makes sense (see my considerations at the end).

First I wanted to implement the following example using **Table-Per-Concrete**. But then I read several times that you **should only do this when you really have performance problems** and you **should use table per type** as long as you have no performance problems.

So the following relations are given:

```
system_user (system_user_id, type, first_name, last_name, ...)

user (system_user_id) *Has no unique attributes but special relations accessible only for him, e.g. orders
customer (system_user_id, company_name, ...)
supporter (system_user_id, nickname, ...)
```

So far so good, but I was wondering how **to ensure** in the above example that:

- The type cannot be changed.
- A system_user has at most one entry in an extension.

**My consideration:**

- A trigger that throws an error if the type is changed during an UPDATE.
- One trigger for each extension, which checks before an INSERT, if an entry with this system_user_id already exists in another extension.

**Does this make sense? Or am I going about it the wrong way? Is this even necessary? Should I create a separate relation for each entity directly?**

Maybe I have too much of an object-oriented software developer view on it. Thanks a lot for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you data model makes sense. I would add `type` to the "subclass" tables, create a unique constraint on `(system_user_id, type)` and create foreign key relationships pointing to `system_user`. Then add a check constraint to the subclass tables that makes sure that `type` has the correct value.

This avoids using a trigger.

Comment: Oh thank you, that sounds like a smart solution. I will try that!

Comment: Btw what just went through my mind. Would you design the attribute "Type" as int2 or would you capture an enum for better readability?

Comment: Use enums only if you are very certain that you will never have to remove an enum value, because that's impossible. Other than that, it doesn't matter.

Comment: This is a good and important point, I had completely forgotten.